# Quartiles from Raster Layer band

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, statistics, plugins

I'm building a plugin from QGIS, and I need to extract the values from the quartiles from a band in a raster layer.
Does anyone knows how it is done?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers which solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use an adaptation of the next code (by using the path of your particular raster):

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

raster = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/utah_demUTM2.tif"

dataset = gdal.Open(raster)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

print "rows = %d columns = %d" % (band.YSize, band.XSize)

BandType = gdal.GetDataTypeName(band.DataType)

print "Data type = ", BandType

data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, band.XSize, band.YSize)

p25 = np.percentile(data, 25) # return 25th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(data, 50) # return 50th percentile.
p75 = np.percentile(data, 75) # return 75th percentile.

print "p25 = {} p50 = {} p75 = {} ".format (p25, p50, p75)

dataset = None
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS the results were:

```
rows = 791 columns = 1680
Data type =  Int16
p25 = 1529.0 p50 = 1739.0 p75 = 2072.0
```